# How to create multiple dropdowns with the same attribute

Tags: jsp, html-select, struts, struts-1

I'm using Struts 1.3 and I want to be able to provide dropdowns for different options as follows:

The below examples have this format:

```
Radio button:   dropdown value 1
                dropdown value 2

English: good morning
         hello
     
French: bonjour
        salut
    
Spanish: buenos dias
         hola
```

I have a map that looks as follows:

```
[[English, {good morning, hello}][French, {bonjoue, salut}][Spanish, {buenos dias, hola}]]
```

so my JSP would look something like this (semi-pseudocode):

```
For each item in the map:
   set optionList = item.values;
   
    If item.key == English {
        Radio button English:
    }
    
    If item.key == French {
        Radio button French:
     }

    If item.key == Spanish 
      Radio button Spanish:
    }
    <html:select property="salutation">
           <html:optionsCollection name="optionList" label="key" value="value"/>
    </html:select>
End for each
```

The problem is that at I end up with tis:

```
English: good morning
     hello
     bonjour
     salut
     buenos dias
     hola
     
French:  good morning
     hello
     bonjour
     salut
     buenos dias
     hola

Spanish: good morning
     hello
     bonjour
     salut
     buenos dias
     hola
```

I would have assumed the optionList would get printed with the right values on each iteration but that doesn't seem to be the case. I also tried duplicating the html:select code inside each of the IF statements but it's the same result, it seems to evaluate after.

I'm open to better suggestions of implementing this. Please let me know if I need to clarify further.

Comment: The issue was in the java code, I was not creating a new map object after each iteration so all i was doing was passing 1 single map with all the values. The JSP works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using an `entrySet()` of the map for the options collection.

But you need to get a list of options by the `key` from the `Map`.

Use an iterator of the `keySet()` of the map and define the options collection as a value.